# Add a search bar in asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, searchbar

I need to add a search bar on my index page, and the result of the research will be show on another page.

What I've tried:

The view

```
<form class="row contact-form rounded-pill link no-gutters" id="contact-form-data">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("RechercheResto", "Client", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 d-inline-block d-lg-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><i class="lni lni-restaurant" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                <input type="text" name="nomResto" placeholder="Nom du restaurant" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-2 d-none" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input type="submit" class="btn main-btn rounded-pill w-100 h-100 contact_btn" value="Rechercher le restaurant" />
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

The controller

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RechercheResto(string nomResto)
{
    var restoList = from r in db.Restaurants select r;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomResto))
    {
        restoList = restoList.Where(r => r.name.Contains(nomResto));
    }
    return View(restoList.ToList());
}
```

Comment: If you want the search results to show on another page, you should post the form to that other page. It looks like you're posting it to itself. The controller for the other page will be responsible for displaying the page with search results

Comment: Can you please edit your question and clarify what the problem is?  Is `restoList` not giving the results you expect?  Is your view not displaying the results?  Or what?

Comment: @devlincarnate when i enter some text in the search bar an validate it reload the index page. The only change is on the url of the page

Comment: @Jonathan i will try it an will reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of returning View(restoList.ToList()) you can add viewname in first parameter and second will be your result.ToList().

Comment: Not sure how much this will be answering your question, but I think you are trying to create a search bar as we have on top of StackOverflow? If yes, then you can do one thing remove the form tag and post-call from there and when you click on the search button write your custom method and pass that search string to another page with querystring for example:- q=searchtext then perform your actual search and display output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I've just find the solution. The problem was the  I put before the BeginForm.

The working code look like that

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RechercheResto", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new { @class= "row contact-form rounded-pill link no-gutters"}))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 d-inline-block d-lg-flex align-items-center">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label><i class="lni lni-restaurant" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nomResto" placeholder="Nom du restaurant" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin mr-2 d-none" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn main-btn rounded-pill w-100 h-100 contact_btn" value="Rechercher le restaurant" />
                            </div>
                        }
```